# how to make one flask application with multiple clones for each user that use the flask application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

i would like to know how to run multiple instance of flask application or server while using the same ip address

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i can provide code but its a general code that contain boolean and when someone clicks it it will change boolean value

Comment: if you have registered only one domain then you will have to run every application separatelly with different PORT - and users will have to use different PORTs to access different pages. Eventually you can run it behind web server Apache or Nginx and it may redirect different subfolders to different port. And if you will have registered different domains then Apache or Nginx can redirect different domains to different ports.And this is called `virtual hosts`. And this is how most web servers works. Apache doc: [example of virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)